# How to Update and Create record in DB - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Hey All I am new to Laravel Eloquent.

I have a table called account id, that I need to write and update data.

when I try to update existing record it is working,
However if the record not exists I need to add the record to the DB.

this is my code

```
AccountID::where('account_id', '=' ,$account_id) -> where('screen_type', '=', "ctv") -> update($update_account_ctv);
    
 AccountID::where('account_id', '=' ,$account_id) -> where('screen_type', '=', "app") -> update($update_account_app);
    
AccountID::where('account_id', '=' ,$account_id) -> where('screen_type', '=', "site") -> update($update_account_site);
```

How I can resolve this issue that will create a record if the record not exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use `updateOrCreate` like this

```
TableA::updateOrCreate(
    ['account_id' => $account_id, 'screen_type' => 'ctv'],
    ['columnUpdate' => $data]
);
```

In the example below, if a flight exists with a `departure` location of `Oakland` and a `destination` location of `San Diego`, its `price` and `discounted` columns will be updated. If no such flight exists, a new flight will be created which has the attributes resulting from merging the first argument array with the second argument array:

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

Comment: I do not understand just replace the update to Update or create? since you changed all the syntax

Comment: You can read more details at here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts